# In what case does the star doubler option appear after losing a game in Sky Force Reloaded?

Tags: android, sky-force-reloaded

In [Sky Force Reloaded](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.SkyForceReloaded2016&hl=en_US&gl=US), when losing a game, a star doubler option appears sometimes but not always:

[image]

In what case does the star doubler option appear after losing a game in Sky Force Reloaded?